# NextAuth credentials not saving in state

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

Im using nextAuth with my own database of users (mongoDb) and i want the person to be able to sign in with their credentials. The problem is my user object is not being persisted in state, This seems to be a design choice by the people at nextAuth to discourage usernames and passwords, They have said:

```
If you use a custom credentials provider user accounts will not be 
persisted in a database by NextAuth.js (even if one is configured)
```

This seems like a massive hinderance.... I currently doing this to get past it and am wondering what the downside is here:

```
 async authorize(credentials) {

        // check if the user exists in the database
        let user = await db.collection('users').findOne({username:credentials.username})

        if (user && user.password == credentials.password) {
          // return the user object returned from the database
          // because next auth will not save this is state
          return {name: {user}}
        } else {
          return {name: null, email: null, image: null}
        }
      }
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I've been trying to figure out how to return all my user data and finally this worked! return {name: {user}}

Answer (score 0):

The downside is that you will have to manage the security aspects of saving passwords in databases yourself.

We usually recommend third-party providers who have battle-tested systems for keeping your passwords secure. If you are fine with rolling your own solution, there is nothing wrong with it.

As a warning note ⚠, just from your code above, I already see a **HUGE** security problem. You seem to store passwords as plain text in your database. If your db ever gets leaked, ALL your user's accounts will be available to the hacker immediately.